# [MATLAB]: Fourier Series - Conversion to logical from sym is not possible

Tags: matlab, while-loop, fft

I'm trying to calculate/plot the Fourier Series of a function in MATLAB. The function is

`f(t) = 1-cos(t) for [-pi,0] and f(t) = t/pi for [0,pi].`

I need to find how many terms in the series are needed to approximate the original signal with 99% of the average energy. I'm trying to use a while loop to do it, but can't seem to get the comparison condition to work. The full code is below.

```
clear all

n = 0;
syms t;

f1 = 1-cos(t);
f2 = t/pi;

e1 = int((abs(f1))^2,-pi,0);
e2 = int((abs(f2))^2, 0, pi);

e_av = (1/(2*pi)) * (e1 + e2);

for k = 1 : 11
c_n(k) = subs((1/(2*pi)) * (int((f1 * exp(-1j*n*2*pi*t)),-pi,0) + int((f2 * exp(-1j*n*2*pi*t)), 0, pi)));
n=n+1;
end

sum = c_n(1).^2;
i = 2;

while (sum < 0.9075)
    sum = sum + 2*c_n(i).^2;
    i = i+1;
end

display(i)
display(sum)
```

The 0.9075 is 99% of e_av.

I kind of understand what the error means, I'm assuming MATLAB reads sum as a symbolic variable for some reason, and you can't compare a sym to a logical. But when first defined, where `sum = c_n(1).^2;`, it's a value, not a sym (c_n(1) is cn0, the first Fourier Coefficient). Is the symbolic variable t somehow carrying over into c_n even after being integrated out? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: `class(c_n)` returns `sym`, so use `double` for conversion. Inside loop as well

Comment: Thanks @brainkz. Here's the code I changed:                                                                      `sum = double(c_n(1)).^2;
i = 2;

while (sum < 0.9075)
    sum = sum + 2*double(c_n(i)).^2;
    i = i+1;
end`
And here's the error:                                                                                `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in sym/subsref (line 805)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);
Error in Q2 (line 23)
    sum = sum + 2*double(c_n(i)).^2;`

Comment: I have no idea, but quick look reveals complex numbers in c_n. Try troubleshoot there